# UISegmentedControl iOS 13 SelectedTint Default Color

Tags: swift, ios13, xcode11

I would like to match the default `SelectedTintColor` from the `UISegmentControl` to another view but I cannot find a matching color from the default system* colors provided in Attribute Inspector.

The background seems to be `.quaternarySystemFill` but there is no color which matches the selected color in both light and dark mode.

Even setting the color this way does not work since the `.selectedSegmentTintColor` returns `nil`:

```swift
label.backgroundColor = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentTintColor
```

Does anyone know the correct color or do I need to do this with a custom color?

*Edit:*
[image: UISegmentedControl_light]
[image: UISegmentedControl_dark]

*Edit 2:*
Currently this line kind of works, but maybe there is a better way?

```swift
label.backgroundColor = label.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light ? .white : .tertiaryLabel
```

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding of your question, you want to change the background color same as UISegmentControl tint color. What you need to do is simply use this:

```
label.backgroundColor = segmentedControl.tintColor
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks! The `.tintcolor` is set to default in storyboard but does not affect the view at all. For example if I set this to `.systemPink`, the selected index is still white/grey. I added two images to my question.

Comment: Ok, I got the issue now you just need to give its background color to clear from storyboard. This is happening due to default background selection and default selection is as per theme. Once you set the segmentControl background color to clear you will get the required result.
Thanks it this helps vote up.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change anything either. Maybe this did work in previous iOS versions but they did change things in iOS13. If I change the `selectedSegmentTintColor ` in attribute inspector, it does change the color of the selected index correctly but if I leave it on default, it does return `nil` if I try to access it programmatically via swift.

Comment: Try to set your UISegmentcontrol background color to clear in viewDidLoad, you will get your result. I have tried this and it worked for me.

`segment.backgroundColor = Color.clear`

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background same as the segment bar tint color you can try:

```
yourLabel.backgroundColor  = segmentControl.tintColor.
```

I tried with

var myNormalFont = UIFont.FromName("OpenSans-SemiBold", 19f);
            var myNormalTextColor = UIColor.LightGray;
            AlertsSegmentedControl.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { Font = myNormalFont, TextColor = myNormalTextColor }, UIControlState.Normal);
            var mySelectedFont = UIFont.FromName("OpenSans-SemiBold", 19f);
            var mySelectedTextColor = UIColor.White;
            AlertsSegmentedControl.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { Font = mySelectedFont, TextColor = mySelectedTextColor }, UIControlState.Selected);
            AlertsSegmentedControl.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this did not work either, as mentioned in the comments of the previous answer.

Comment: did you set your segmentcontrol's background to .clear?